# How does `Yacc` identifies function calls?

Tags: yacc

I am trying to figure out how yacc identifies function calls in a C code. For Example: if there is a function call like **my_fun(a,b)**; then which rules does this statement reduces to. 
I am using the cGrammar present in : [C Grammar](https://gist.github.com/codebrainz/2933703)

Following the Grammar given over there manually; I figured out that we only have two choices in translation unit. Everything has to either be a function definition or a declaration. Now all declaration starts type_specifiers, storage_class_specifier etc but none of them starts with IDENTIFIER

Now in case of a function call the name would be IDENTIFIER. This leaves me unclear as to how it will be parsed and which rules will be used exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official `yacc` specification specified here [yacc](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/), everything is handled by user given routines. When you have a function call the name of course is **IDENTIFIER**.It is parsed using the user defined procedures.According to the specifications, the user can specify his input in terms of individual input characters, or in terms of higher level constructs such as names and numbers. The user-supplied routine may also handle idiomatic features such as comment and continuation conventions, which typically defy easy grammatical specification.

Do have a look.By the way you are supposed to do a thorough research before putting questions here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have actually done some research on them but since I am very new to it my efforts have been less fruitful. I looked through different yacc files for C. But the grammar I went through does not have any rule to identify function calls. I understand that user has to put it but shouldn't it be there for any complete grammar file. Yacc specifies that user has to define it but for an already defined grammar, do we need to add those rules ?

Comment: @Sharad I believe that is the case. Now you can either mark the question as answered or you can wait for maybe better answers.